# Saving a highscore for Game Center in Swift 2

Tags: ios, game-center, xcode7, swift2, game-center-leaderboard

I recently migrated to swift 2 after downloading Xcode 7 beta and i found 2 errors that I fixed using product>clean. I am still stuck with 2 Game Centre related errors。Below is my code to save the highscore. (If it helps, this code is present on two view controllers, with a difference in leaderboard id's and score variables)

```
func saveHighscore(score:Int) {

    //check if user is signed in
    if GKLocalPlayer.localPlayer().authenticated {

        var scoreReporter = GKScore(leaderboardIdentifier: "ChineseWeather") //leaderboard id here

        scoreReporter.value = Int64(Score) //score variable here (same as above)

        var scoreArray: [GKScore] = [scoreReporter]

        GKScore.reportScores(scoreArray, withCompletionHandler: {(error : NSError!) -> Void in
            if error != nil {
                print("error")
            }
        })

    }

}
```

In the line where it starts with GKScore I receive the following error:

Cannot invoke 'reportScores' with an argument list of type '([GKScore], withCompletionHandler: (NSError!) -> Void)'

So I tried to fix this by adding scores: before scoreArray as follows:

```
GKScore.reportScores(scores: scoreArray, withCompletionHandler: {(error : NSError!) -> Void in
```

And it gives me the following error:

Missing argument for parameter 'withEligibleChallenges' in call

Help would be greatly appreciated and thank you in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [prerelease documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKScore_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/GKScore/reportScores:withCompletionHandler:), the method signature has changed to be:

```
class func reportScores(_ scores: [GKScore],
  withCompletionHandler completionHandler: ((NSError?) -> Void)?)
```

This differs from the [old documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKScore_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/GKScore/reportScores:withCompletionHandler:) which stated:

```
class func reportScores(_ scores: [AnyObject]!,
  withCompletionHandler completionHandler: ((NSError!) -> Void)!)
```

Note the change to an optional NSError parameter as well as making the entire handler optional.

So you'll have to change your code to not have the explicit `error: NSError!` as your completion block parameter.

Comment: You can just change your code from `(error : NSError!) -> Void` to `error -> Void`. Alternatively just use shorthand $0 syntax.

Comment: I fixed the function call but in the code where I had "if error =! nil" now gives an error because there is no declaration of error. If I try error: NSError it says it's wrong.